# Script won't run in order

Tags: python, python-import

I have this python script that will not run in the correct order I want it to. Here is the code:

```
import VT as vt
import VT_Tests
import AUTO as auto


def main():
    auto.run()
    vt.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want it to run the `AUTO` module first but its just jumping right to the other one first.

Comment: @Elazar what does that mean exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The body of the module is executed in the `import` statement. Your problem is probably that you are VT_Tests is calling `vt.run()` in its body - it shouldn't. You should test for `__name__` just like you did here before calling anything you don't want to be called upon import.

Comment: It's still running in the wrong order even after re-ordering it like you said.

Comment: @bbesase only if one is calling the other somehow, or if AUTO imports VT. if this is the case, there's nothing (sensible) you can do, unless you can change the VT or VT_Tests modules

Comment: AUTO doesn't import VT or VT_Tests, AUTO and VT are just two separate scripts. The scripts are very long I don't think I can post them

Comment: You don't have to post here all these scripts - just the related parts (function definition, and anywhere it is being called).

Comment: @bbesase what happens if you don't import VT_Tests? I guess VT_Tests calls `vt.run()`.